# Variables in UIBinder xml

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I am new to GWT and can not find an answer to this: I have got a nice UIBinder for a TextBox, it works, I have UIHandler working with it, ok. But what if I want to show a value from this TextBox all over my HTML? Is there a way to declare one variable to reuse this value all over HTML, or should i declare new Label with new ui:field name every time I want to show the value on one html page, and fill every such a Label with UIHandler (wich I could do right away, but this seems really boring)?

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder' xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui">
<g:HTMLPanel>
    <g:TextBox  ui:field="myField"/><br/>        
    <div>            
        <p>                
            What do I need to put here if i want to see **myField.getValue()** in html, may be even multiple times? 
            And **here**?
            I want to avoid creation of new and new objects in back-end class for just one value, multiple labels here are ok. How to push one value in all of them, when myField content is changed?
        </p>            
    </div>
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two approaches to designing GUI in code in MVC (whatever that means) way:

- GUI is smart and pulls data from model, usually when certain events happen (data binding falls into this category),
- GUI is stupid, so the data is pushed into view by a controller (it is sometimes called a [passive view](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PassiveScreen.html)).

Both have their pros and their cons, but the important thing is: when you try to combine them, the pros cancel each other, and cons - accumulate. That is you end up with disadvantages of each pattern and a big mess.

UIbinder is a tool that helps you build a stupid view, as used in MVP pattern. It helps you easily create a bunch of objects that will redraw parts of view when you push data into them. They are not supposed to be intelligent entities. So the boring way seems to be the way to go.

Not wanting to use a label is, btw, a little strange: you **need** an object to update parts of the ui (it's Java, using objects is what we do!). It just so happens that such type of object exists and is called `Label`. Would you like it more if the very same class was called `AnAutomaticHtmlUpdaterThatRequiresNoLabelWhatsoever`?

Comment: In this particular case I need to update one value in several labels in html. So, i don't mind to create 15 Label objects in the ui xml, I just wonder if there is a way to bind all of them to one variable, or I should bind every one to 15 different objects in backend class and update all of them in UIHandler when my TextBox fires a change event?

Comment: There is some <ui:with> tag I am trying to play around, it looks like the thing I look for.

Comment: no, <ui:with> is not what you were looking for :) it seems that my answer was right (hint hint)